# dpkg-buildpackage fails with compiler error for openssh-6.6p1 (Ubuntu 14.04.3)

Tags: ssh, debian, ubuntu-14.04

I need to rebuild openssh to turn on audit logging.

So (as root):

```
apt-get openssh
apt-get build-dep openssh
dpkg-source -x openssh_6.6p1-2ubuntu2.3.dsc
```

edit debian/rules, add:

```
confflags += --with-audit=linux
```

after

```
confflags += --with-ssl-engine

./configure
make
dpkg-buildpackage -b
```

......

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wuninitialized -Wsign-compare -Wformat-security -Wsizeof-pointer-memaccess -Wno-pointer-sign -Wno-unused-result -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -ftrapv -fno-builtin-memset -fstack-protector-all -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -DLOGIN_PROGRAM=\"/bin/login\" -DLOGIN_NO_ENDOPT -DSSH_EXTRAVERSION=\"Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3ubuntu1audit\"  -I. -I..  -I/usr/include/editline     -I/usr/include/ConsoleKit/ck-connector -I/usr/include/dbus-1.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dbus-1.0/include   -DSSHDIR=\"/etc/ssh\" -D_PATH_SSH_PROGRAM=\"/usr/bin/ssh\" -D_PATH_SSH_ASKPASS_DEFAULT=\"/usr/bin/ssh-askpass\" -D_PATH_SFTP_SERVER=\"/usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server\" -D_PATH_SSH_KEY_SIGN=\"/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-keysign\" -D_PATH_SSH_PKCS11_HELPER=\"/usr/lib/openssh/ssh-pkcs11-helper\" -D_PATH_SSH_PIDDIR=\"/var/run\" -D_PATH_PRIVSEP_CHROOT_DIR=\"/var/run/sshd\" -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -c ../sshd.c

In file included from ../openbsd-compat/sys-tree.h:29:0,
                 from ../sshd.c:56:
./config.h:1606:0: warning: "SUPERUSER_PATH" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define SUPERUSER_PATH "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
 ^

In file included from ../includes.h:171:0,
                 from ../sshd.c:45:
../defines.h:399:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 # define SUPERUSER_PATH _PATH_STDPATH
 ^

In file included from ../openbsd-compat/sys-tree.h:29:0,
                 from ../sshd.c:56:
./config.h:1615:0: warning: "USER_PATH" redefined [enabled by default]
 #define USER_PATH "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
 ^

In file included from ../includes.h:19:0,
                 from ../sshd.c:45:
../config.h:1615:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
 #define USER_PATH "/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin"
 ^

In file included from ../openbsd-compat/openbsd-compat.h:157:0,
                 from ../includes.h:174,
                 from ../sshd.c:45:
**../openbsd-compat/bsd-misc.h:122:39: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘while’**
 # define krb5_free_error_message(a,b) while(0)
```

Does anyone know the solution to resolve this?

I tried placing the `while(0)` part in `()` or `{}`, but that didn't help.

I didn't have this problem with 14.04.0.

Any advice/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You should run the configure with all the the flags from `confflags`. If you don't use them, it might fail like this

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I have a debian/rules file that defines all of my confflags defined. I assume configure reads that file and acts accordingly. Is that not correct?

Comment: `./configure` configures with default flags, which is not what you want. You want to add content of `confflags` which you edited, but didn't use if I understand well your post. >> No, configure does not read any debian stuff.

Comment: By the way, your question almost certainly belongs on [so], but many of us frequent [su] as well! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`make` and `configure` are part of a standard Unix (i.e. *not* Debian-specific) toolchain for building software. It's no surprise that Debian uses them internally, however it most likely wraps each part of the build process in a command of its own, so that it can control how `configure` and `make` get called. This is what you want, since you don't know (and don't *want* to know) all of the innane little details needed to get Debian's build process to "hi-jack" `make` and `configure` successfully.

I've never tried [rebuilding a Debian package](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=rebuild+a+debian+package+with+different+confflags), but as I suspected, there is a [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage) for it. Sure enough, I found the command for building a package [there](https://wiki.debian.org/BuildingAPackage#Building_the_modified_package):

```
fakeroot debian/rules clean
fakeroot debian/rules binary
```

The `fakeroot` command allows you to run any program which requires root access as a non-root user. This is good, because `gcc` is not designed to run as root, and really shouldn't, ever. However, if that doesn't bother you, you can skip installing `fakeroot`, and just run

```
debian/rules binary
```

directly. As I said, I've never tried this, so let me know if it works! :-)